# filtering strings of particular length from file

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7, extract

I have a foo.txt file with contents

```
'w3ll' 'i' '4m' 'n0t' '4sed' 't0' 

'it'
```

and i am trying to extract all words with 2 characters in them . I mean ,The output file should only have

```
4m
t0
it
```

What I tried is,

```
with open("foo.txt" , 'r') as foo:
    listme = foo.read()

string =  listme.strip().split("'")
```

This will split the strings with ' sign , i suppose. 
How can I select only those string within those apostrophe sign whose character count is equal to 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to find all the words contained in `''` symbols, that are exactly two characters long:

```
import re
split = re.compile(r"'\w{2}'")

with open("file2","w") as fw:
    for word in split.findall(open("file","r").read()):
            fw.write(word.strip("'")+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
>>> with open('abc') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
...     for line in f:
...         for word in line.split():    #split the line at whitespaces
...             word = word.strip("'")   # strip out `'` from each word
...             if len(word) == 2:       #if len(word) is 2 then write it to file
...                 f2.write(word + '\n')

print open('output.txt').read()
4m
t0
it
```

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('abc') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
        words = re.findall(r"'(.{2})'",line)
        for word in words:
            f2.write(word + '\n')
...             
>>> print open('output.txt').read()
4m
t0
it
```

Comment: @abhikafle Any error? please post such examples in question body not in comments, as they are not readable.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini . but the regex method takes two diffrent string separated by comma as one .   when i ran the code to find 20 char. word , it gave me   "', 9, '1186148119', '' " as output , which is still valid , but it consists of many different strings , not just one.

Comment: @abhikafle your example input input doesn't contain any `','` that's why I didn't handle them. Please post such things in question itself.

Comment: can you please add   ',' as marking  to separate two strings?

Comment: @abhikafle In the first code replace `line.split()` with `line.split(', ')`

Comment: The first one didn't help me. I need some kind of modification using regex to filter unwanted output.

Comment: @abhikafle Please post your sample input and expected output in question body.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("foo.txt" , 'r') as file:
  words = [word.strip("'") for line in file for word in line.split() if len(word) == 4]

with open("out", "w") as out:
  out.write('\n'.join(words) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading quoted words separated by spaces (or commas) you could use the csv module:

```
import csv

with open('/tmp/2let.txt','r') as fin, open('/tmp/out.txt','w') as fout:
    reader=csv.reader(fin,delimiter=' ',quotechar="'")
    source=(e for line in reader for e in line)             
    for word in source:
        if len(word)<=2:
            print(word)
            fout.write(word+'\n')
```

'out.txt':

```
i
4m
t0
```